# Adding submodule converted from cvs to history of superproject

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-cvs

I'm converting a CVS repo with a lot of modules to git.

Some of the modules I'm just going to combine with the main project in to one repo.  But I want to keep 3 others as git submodules.

While developing the project in CVS, all 4 directories were tagged with the same tags.  That way I can check out a complete version of the project.

I can convert 4 pieces of my CVS repo to 4 git repos.  No problem.

But when I then check out one repo as the superproject and add the other 3 as submodules, they only exist in the version I then commit.

What I want is to be able to check out previous tags of the project (which are now tags in the git repo) and the associated tag in the submodules.  I guess I need a ".gitmodules" file to appear in all those prior tags.

How do I do that?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0):

You have to go into each submodule and repeat the command - assuming the same tags exist there.

```
git submodule foreach
```

command is useful in this case.

Comment: depends on what you need to do. If you want to checkout a tag, you can do so with `git submodule foreach git checkout rel1.2`. This assumes what you stated earlier that you will repeat tags into each of the modules.